# Eggs won't hatch while travelling on a boat

Tags: pokemon-go

I'm on a boat and the average speed is about 15 km/h, but the egg progress does not change. It worked fine the first day but now it doesn't. It usually works when I'm near land and travel slower so I guess it only works near land now? Or is the speed required different while at sea?

I could not have been banned since I haven't cheated or even played the game while going too fast. In addition, I really doubt it has anything to do with connection issues, since I'm writing this while travelling and I haven't had any problems thus far. Lastly, this has been happening over the course if a week at the moment. So, the same problem seems to occur as distance only counts when travelling near land as not even ~5mph speeds don't count towards hatching eggs so I'm guessing egg grinding is not supposed to happen at sea.

Comment: in the sea  there are not pokestops (only very near land) and also no pokemon. i dont think Niantic expects going on boat to hatch so i guess you should only be very near land.

Comment: Oh... I was on a boat too in the middle of a lake once, and wanted to login to see if there is a secret gyarados in the lake, get egg distance, but couldn't log in at all (although that might have been a server problem). In any case, seems like the game was designed for mainly land playing, and known water routes like popular ferries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your eggs not hatching is independent of your mode of transit. This means that whether you are on a boat or not does not affect your eggs hatching. What does affect distance being recorded is connection to the internet, travel speed, and being soft banned.

**Connection to the internet** - when you visit a lake, often you are going to remote places with no wifi and poor cell coverage. Thus, if the app cannot accurately track your location and connect to Niantic servers, you distance will not be tracked for your eggs. Check your available networks and reassure that you still have ample data coverage on your boat.

**Travel speed** - it is now confirmed by a large number of players that traveling too fast can affect egg hatching. It is a general consensus among players that the maximum speed for hatching eggs is ~10-12mph (15km/h is about 9.3mph), so perhaps consider slowing down, as you are traveling at just about the maximum speed for tracking egg hatching distance. You can reference this question for more about speed: [How fast can I travel?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/280819/how-fast-can-i-travel/280830)

**Soft ban** - if you have been recorded for cheating via GPS spoofing or any other form of cheating, you will likely be soft-banned (or banned for a short amount of time). When you are soft banned, you cannot catch Pokemon (they all run away), some distances don't track, and you can't get items from PokeStops. Refer to this question for more about soft bans: [Why can't I catch Pokemon in Pokemon Go anymore?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/274315/why-cant-i-catch-pokemon-in-pokemon-go-anymore)

In addition, if it worked yesterday and doesn't work today, it might just be a server issue with Niantic, and will resolve itself in time. It's a bit hard to conclude anything with only 24 hours of evidence, but wait a little longer and try again. If your distance is still not tracking, consider one of the above prognoses.

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed that Pokemon GO doesn't count distance traveled above 'sea' blocks on map. This is probably because unless you are swimming with your phone moving is impossible and only way to move would be considered cheating. However, you can find Pokemons from sea or water if you stay close to coast.

Answer (score -1):

It might help you are not, one day I was walking on a field without any road near it and my egg weren't hatching even if I had connexion.

Maybe you have to be on or near roads because Niantic uses Google maps ?